# Gibt es ein Wort für die Klasse vor der Abiturklasse?

Tags: single-word-request, technical-terminology, education

Ich möchte wissen, ob es ein Wort für die Klasse vor der Abiturklasse gibt.

An deutschen Schulen, ist dies das 12. Jahr oder das 11. Jahr (falls man das [Abitur nach der zwölften Jahrgangsstufe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abitur_nach_der_zw%C3%B6lften_Jahrgangsstufe) macht).

Die Schüler sind meistens sechszehn oder siebzehn Jahre alt.

Wann es keine bestimmten Wörter gibt, sind Ausdrücke auch gut.

Comment: Da beide Jahrgänge der Sekundarstufe II ins Abitur einfließen, gibt es für die Schüler dieser Klassenstufe nicht notwendigerweise einen besonderen Namen. Mir ist kein gebräuchlicher Name geläufig.

Comment: @Chieron: „Beide Jahrgänge der Sekundarstufe II“ paßt nicht so recht, weil die Sekundarstufe II in Deutschland drei Jahren umfaßt (und in den anderen deutschsprachigen Ländern noch mehr).

Comment: "Die Studenten sind" - ich habe die Grammatik hierzu korrigiert; die Wortwahl ist jedoch noch nicht ganz richtig: Es müsste *Schüler* heißen. Im Deutschen bezeichnet man ausschließlich diejenigen als *Studenten*, die eine Hochschule besuchen, alle anderen sind *Schüler*.

Comment: Nachdem es das Abitur nur in Deutschland gibt, ist der Hinweis auf deutsche Schulen redundant. In anderen Ländern in denen Deutsch eine Amtssprache ist (Österreich, Schweiz, Liechtenstein, Italien) heißt die Reifeprüfung »Matura«. In Österreich macht man die Matura je nach am Ende der 8. Klasse einer AHS oder am Ende der 9. Klasse einer BHS. Die Klasse davor ist dann die 7. oder 8. Klasse. (In Österreich folgt auf die 4. Klasse Volksschule die 1. Klasse des anschließenden Schultyps)

Comment: Ich wüsste kein gesondertes Wort für den vorletzten Jahrgang. Die beiden letzten Jahre kenne ich als *Oberstufe* oder *Kursstufe*.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Für _Oberstufe_ gilt dasselbe wie für _Sekundarstufe II_: Sie umfaßt die letzten drei Jahre. Ein Bezug auf Kurse würde passen, oder sonst offiziell _Qualifizierungsphase_.

Comment: Warum das Verb:"gibt" ist nicht am Ende des Satzes in "ob es ein Wort..." war das grammatisch korrekt Struktur?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast : und gibt es in Österreich für diese vorletzte Schulklasse einen Namen? So unterschiedlich sind die Systeme nicht, abgesehen von der Bezeichnung des Abschlusses.

Comment: @user1474062 : nein, es war nicht grammatisch korrekt. korrigiert,

Comment: @chirlu Fast hätte ich an meiner Erinnerung gezweifelt, aber lt. Wikipedia-Artikel zur Gymnasialen Oberstufe ist es länder- und  systemabhängig, welche Jahrgänge zur Oberstufe zählen: G9 11-13, G8 10-12 oder 11-12. Als Beispiele für die letzte Variante werden Bayern und Sachsen genannt. Willkommen im föderalen Bildungssystem ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Früher wurden Klassenstufen teilweise [mit lateinischen Ordinalzahlen benannt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahrgangsstufe#Vom_Sextaner_zum_Primaner): Sexta, Quinta usw. In diesem System war die vorletzte Klasse die *Unterprima*, die Schüler in ihr *Unterprimaner*.

Diese Benennung ist allerdings seit fünfzig Jahren nicht mehr üblich und dürfte von der Mehrzahl der Sprecher nicht mehr verstanden werden.

Comment: Außerdem geht diese Nomenklatur traditionell von 13 Schuljahren bis zum Abitur aus. Für G8 werden ggf. _Untertertia_ und _Obertertia_ zur _Tertia_ zusammengelegt, sodass nur _Sekunda_ und _Prima_ in _Ober~_ und _Unter~_ geteilt sind. _Sextaner_ (d.h. Fünftklässler) [hört oder liest man noch ab und zu](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Sextaner%2CQuintaner%2CQuartaner%2CTertianer%2CSekundaner%2CPrimaner%2CUnterprimaner%2COberprimaner%2CObersekundaner%2CUntersekundaner&year_start=1788&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3) als Synonym für Neulinge oder Anfänger.

Comment: Vor 30 Jahren waren die lateinischen Namen noch gang und gäbe. Das includiert die geburtenstarken Jahrgänge, so dass ein Großteil der Sprecher mit den Begriffen sicher mehr oder weniger vertraut ist - womöglich jedoch kaum bei ehemaligen Real- und Hauptschülern.

Comment: @userunknown Ich nehme an, Du beziehst Dich auf das Gebiet der damaligen Bundesrepublik? Oder auf bedtimmte Bundesländer? Im Osten jedenfalls wurden diese Begriffe vor 30 nicht mehr verwendet.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Stimmt, den Osten übersehen. Ich nehme an Du meinst "vor 30 Jahren", nicht 1930.

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt, die Jahre sind mit abhanden gekommenen

Answer (score 3):

Der Jahresbericht meiner Kinder weist **Q1** als Abkürzung für *Qualifizierungsstufe 1* (vorletzte Klasse) und **Q2** für *Qualifizierungsstufe 2* (entsprechend dem Abiturjahrgang) aus. Weil Bayern in Schulangelegenheiten schon immer etwas speziell war, kann ich nicht beurteilen, ob das auch anderswo verstanden wird.

Comment: Immerhin relevanter als ein fünfzig Jahre altes System

Comment: _Qualifizierungsphase_ ist ein offizieller, von der Kultusministerkonferenz einheitlich festgelegter Begriff für die letzten zwei Jahre; bei _Qualifizierungsstufe_ bin ich mir nicht sicher, zu meiner Zeit in BW gab es den Begriff jedenfalls nicht. In der Allgemeinbevölkerung dürfte beides nicht unmittelbar verständlich sein.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: Das Sexta-usw.-System war weit älter, vor fünfzig Jahren wurde es im offiziellen Sprachgebrauch _aufgegeben_. Siehe auch [Crissovs Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28997/gibt-es-ein-wort-f%c3%bcr-die-klasse-vor-der-abiturklasse#comment70657_28998) mit dem Ngram-Link.